# Delete field and still query on it?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongo so need some clarification.  In the example below it appears a field is deleted, then is still used somehow to run a query.

From:  [MongoDB The Definitive Guide (2ed, K. Chodorow)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344682) (p.32)

**A user document:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4b2b9f67a1f631733d917a7a"),
"name" : "joe",
"friends" : 32,
"enemies" : 2
}
```

**Storing this document to a variable changing its structure...**

```
> var joe = db.users.findOne({"name" : "joe"});
> joe.relationships = {"friends" : joe.friends, "enemies" : joe.enemies};
{
"friends" : 32,
"enemies" : 2
}> joe.username = joe.name;
"joe"
> delete joe.friends;
true
> delete joe.enemies;
true
```

**...and finally the bit that's confusing:**

```
> delete joe.name;
true
> db.users.update({"name" : "joe"}, joe);
```

Which returns the updated document, but how did the query `{"name" : "joe"}` return the document if we had just deleted the name field (`delete joe.name;`)?

**I must be interpreting something incorrectly.  What is it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `joe` is just an in-memory copy of the actual document in the `users` collection.

So `delete joe.name;` only affects the `joe` copy until the subsequent `db.users.update` call at the end *replaces* the document in the collection with the contents of `joe`. That's why the document could still be found by `{name: 'joe'}` for the update.

Comment: oh, it's a copy, not a reference.  Thanks for clearing that up!